# Sniffing packets of communication with specific domain - Scapy

Tags: python-2.7, networking, ip-address, scapy

What's the best way to sniff packets with the source or destination being a specific domain (for example "www.facebook.com").

And why won't this filter work?

```
def filter_facebook(packet):
        return DNS in packet and "www.facebook.com" in packet
```

I'm new to Scapy so please don't kill me.

Comment: You have few problems here. First, for your mission you need to first capture and analyse DNS packets for the domain and then sniff all the possible answers by IP (the traffic itself does not have 'DNS' in it). I can't see an easier way to do that. I suggest that you use wireshark and see how DNS responses look like. Second, if you're looking for DNS traffic for a specific domain then your query is not correct. For example if you're looking for responses for "www.facebook.com" you should use something like (didn't check) 'DNS in pkt and "www.facebook.com" in pkt['DNS Question Record'].qname'.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.