# Scapy sniffing pakets

Tags: python-2.7, networking, scapy

I am trying to create filter function that check if the packet is from facebook, this is my code :

```
def filter_facebook(packet):
    return (IP in packet and (packet[IP].src == "www.facebook.com" or packet[IP].dst == "www.facebook.com"))
packets = sniff(count = 5, lfilter = filter_facebook)
```

now this function block the continuation and not sniff anything when i am entering to facebook.

Answer (score 0):

> now this function block the continuation and not sniff anything when i
>   am entering to facebook.

This is because no packets match your filter and `sniff()` waits until 5 packets matches it.

First, you can't use "www.facebook.com" as a comparison value with an IP address. You could first sniff DNS traffic to find which addresses are associated with www.facebook.com as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117913/sniffing-packets-of-communication-with-specific-domain-scapy) or find it in another way and then filter with these addresses.

Second, it is a good practice to filter with an interface (`iface`) when sniffing, the one that receive packets from internet in your situation.

Comment: I have changed it to their ip address  ( I have checked it with ping in CMD) but it's still does not work